# Problems at execute a jar file in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, executable-jar

i have to execute a Jar file using NodeJs,
but this jar file consumes a connection.properties
the jar and your requirements like connection.properties is located at the same directory of nodejs file that will execute jar.
i was successfuly at execute the jar file, but the jar can't see the properties that are in the same directory.

When i call the jar, it's response:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: connection.properties (the system can't find the specific file)

and how i'm executing my jar with node

```
let jarReturn = execSync("java -jar myJar.jar params",{ encoding: 'utf8', maxBuffer: 50 * 1024 * 1024 }).toString();
```

Comment: You need to make.sure you are in the samd folder as the jar file.is.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve adding the dir on execSync with cwd and using fs.readdir
example:

```
var dir= path.resolve('myDir');
let jarReturn = "";
fs.readdir(diretorioJar, function (err, files) {
   if (err) {
      return console.log('Unable to scan directory: ' + err);
   } 
files.forEach(function (file) {
   if(file === 'myJar.jar'){
    let jarReturn = execSync(`java -jar "${file}" params`,{ encoding: 'utf8', maxBuffer: 50 * 1024 * 1024, cwd: dir}).toString();
                       
    } 
});
```

});